# Upgrade to Kubuntu 14.04 Hangs at Stopping Cron

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, system-installation, kubuntu, cron

I just attempted to upgrade from Kubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 using the Muon Update utility, but after downloading all required files, the update process stalled with the message *"Cron: Stopping..."*

After several hours, I rebooted, and the machine booted normally. I attempted to run `sudo apt-get -f install` to complete the installation process, but once again, the progress stalled with *"Cron: Stopping..."*

I rebooted once more, and this time, I tried to stop cron manually before doing anything else. The command `sudo service cron stop` hangs up the same way, with no error message. I'm not sure why cron is refusing to stop on request.

Any ideas to get around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just kill the service `cron`,

```
ps aux | grep cron
```

Note down it's pid and then kill that service.

```
sudo kill <pid>
```